# [MFC/C++]Sending CBitmap's bits over socket, and re-construct it on receiver side

Tags: c++, mfc, asyncsocket

I am new with MFC and try to learn it with a project of MFC dialog base on VS2008. Here are the archivements I have done:

First, I have managed to display a list of pictures from a folder to a Listbox Control. After that, I also handled the click event on each line of the listbox to load and show the picture to the Picture Control(type Bitmap) on the right side. You can see the image below for easy understanding: [Please click here for the image of my MFC dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORySi.png)


Here is the code. Note `m_ListCtrl` and `static_picture` are variables of the listbox and the picture control:

```
void CMyClientDlg::OnLbnSelchangeList1(){

CString imagePath;
m_ListCtrl.GetText(m_ListCtrl.GetCurSel(),imagePath);

CImage picture;
picture.Load(imagePath);

if (!picture.IsNull())
{
    float screenWidth = 200, screenHeight = 200;
    float imageWidth = picture.GetWidth();
    float imageHeight = picture.GetHeight();

    //scaling:
    float pictureRatio = imageWidth/ imageHeight;
    float newImageWidth;
    float newImageHeight;
    int aligmentX = 0;
    int aligmentY = 0;
    if (pictureRatio <= 1)
    {
        newImageWidth = imageWidth*(screenHeight/imageHeight);
        newImageHeight = screenHeight;
        aligmentX = (screenWidth-newImageWidth)/2;
    }
    else
    {
        newImageWidth = screenWidth;
        newImageHeight = imageHeight*(screenWidth/imageWidth);
        aligmentY = (screenHeight - newImageHeight)/2;
    }
    //end scaling.
    CDC *screenDC = GetDC();
    CDC mDC;
    mDC.CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);

    CBitmap bitMap;
    bitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(screenDC, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    CBitmap *pob = mDC.SelectObject(&bitMap);
    mDC.SetStretchBltMode(HALFTONE);
    picture.StretchBlt(mDC.m_hDC, aligmentX, aligmentY, newImageWidth, newImageHeight, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, SRCCOPY);
    mDC.SelectObject(pob);

    /*.......code to convert bitmap to BYTE* ........*/
    /*.......code to send BYTE* over socket........*/       

    //display the bit map
    static_picture.SetBitmap((HBITMAP)bitMap.Detach());

    //clean up
    ReleaseDC(screenDC);
}
```

}

So now I would like to advance one more step, and tried to work with socket... and yes, I successfully sent and received simple char* or CString over socket.

What I want to do is: instead showing the picture on this dialog, it shows the image on the other dialog(server).

Somehow I learned that there are 2 funtions that sound work: `SetBitmapBits()` and `GetBitmapBits()` (I honestly just read it on some source and have no idead if they suitable for my goal here).

So, I added this piece of code to turn the above bitmap into array of BYTE `bmpBuffer`:

```
BITMAP bmpProperties;
bitMap.GetBitmap(&bmpProperties);
int bmpDemension = bmpProperties.bmWidthBytes*bmpProperties.bmHeight;
BYTE* bmpBuffer=(BYTE*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, bmpDemension);
bitMap.GetBitmapBits(bmpDemension,bmpBuffer);
```

Then send that array over socket:

```
UpdateData(TRUE);
char *socketBuffer = reinterpret_cast<char*>(bmpBuffer);
send(m_ClientSocket, socketBuffer, sizeof(socketBuffer), 0);
//clean up after send
GlobalFree((HGLOBAL)bmpBuffer);
```

On the other dialog. Note: I have hardcoded the demension of the bitmap to 160000, just to simplify the problem:

```
void CMyServer2Dlg::OnReceive(){    
char *socketBuffer = new char [1025];
int iLen; 
iLen = recv(m_sConnected, socketBuffer, 1025, NULL);
if(iLen==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    AfxMessageBox("Could not Receive");
}
else
{
    BYTE* bmpBuffer = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(socketBuffer);

    //re-construct the bitmap
    CBitmap clone;
    CDC *screenDC = GetDC();
    CDC mDC;
    mDC.CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);

    clone.CreateCompatibleBitmap(screenDC, 200, 200);
    clone.SetBitmapBits(160000,bmpBuffer);

    //Picture control(type bitmap) has variable "static_picture"
    static_picture.SetBitmap((HBITMAP)clone.Detach());

    UpdateData(FALSE);
    ReleaseDC(screenDC);
    GlobalFree((HGLOBAL)bmpBuffer);
}
delete socketBuffer;
```

And, it just doesn't work... Please tell me where did I mess it up? And sorry for the long post.....

Comment: Have a +1 for researching solutions (yes, GetBitmapBits and SetBitmapBits are the right functions, I think). But, what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. On the receiver side, it only display the 200x200 black color, not the image that I have clicked on sender side. I also, tried to re-contruct the bit map on the sender side for testing and it works normally.

Comment: Correct me if wrong. Your receive buffer is 1025, and your bitmap size is 160000. Is the buffer big enough?

Comment: Also, even though you ask to receive 1025 bytes at once, you might not receive them all - you might need to call recv several times to get all the bytes.

Comment: Is there a reason for not sending/receiving the bitmap as bitmap file?

Comment: @EthanF. thanks for your reply, that is also my first suspicion, but after double check the `sizeof(bmpBuffer)` on the sender side, it shows only 4 bytes. And since the data type BYTE is nothing more than the unsigned char, so I guess I made receive buffer 1025 is big enough?

Comment: @TrungNguyen I think sizeof(bmpBuffer) doesn't return the size of the space, instead it's size of the pointer, which is 4 bytes. If the picture is 200x200, it requires 40000/8=5000 bytes. Sure your buffer is not big enough.

Comment: @EthanF. That's true! but like immibis said, I may not receive them all for a one call, how can I do?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani. Yes, sending a whole file seem much easier, but for the sake of the learning, I want to work more on the contruction of bitmap. And, I think in some real circumstances saving file on server side is considered bad practices?

Comment: @TrungNguyen see my answer. 2 mistakes you've made. 1st, you only send 4 bytes, 2nd, you only receive 1025 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most possible reason is that your receiver doesn't get all data of the picture. I suggest you put a size of the bitmap into the package while sending it, for receiver to get correct size.

Here are some sample code. Be aware they are just for showing the idea, you may need some debugging to make sure they work.

step 1: Pack the size of bitmap. I suppose here the size is less than 64K, so a int is used. If size may be bigger than 64k, you may want to use INT64.

```
int bmpDemension = bmpProperties.bmWidthBytes*bmpProperties.bmHeight;
int bufferSize = bmpDemension + sizeof(int);
BYTE* bmpBuffer=(BYTE*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, bufferSize );
bitMap.GetBitmapBits(bmpDemension,bmpBuffer + sizeof(int));
memcpy(bmpBuffer, &bmpDemension, sizeof(int)); // put the size into the head of package.
```

step 2: Send it out
Be aware, I use bufferSize here, because sizeof(bmpBuffer) returns the pointer size, which is 4, not the space size.

```
UpdateData(TRUE);
char *socketBuffer = reinterpret_cast<char*>(bmpBuffer);
send(m_ClientSocket, socketBuffer, bufferSize , 0);
 //clean up after send
GlobalFree((HGLOBAL)bmpBuffer);
```

At the receiver side:
First, you read the size of the bitmap, then do receive according to the size of data.

```
void CMyServer2Dlg::OnReceive(){    
char socketBuffer[1025];
int iLen; 
iLen = recv(m_sConnected, socketBuffer, sizeof(int), NULL); //read the bigmap size
if(iLen==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
AfxMessageBox("Could not Receive");
}
else
{
int dimension = *((int *) socketBuffer);
char * bitmapBuffer = new char[dimension];
int readSize = dimension;
char * pBuffer = bitmapBuffer;
while (readSize > 0)
{
    int sizeToRead = readSize > sizeof(socketBuffer) ? sizeof(socketBuffer) : readSize;
    iLen = recv(m_sConnected, socketBuffer, sizeToRead , NULL);
    memcpy(pBuffer, socketBuffer, iLen);
    pBuffer += iLen;
    readSize -= iLen;
}
// when the loop done, you shall have all data in bitmapBuffer.
....    
// I leave the remaining code to you.
```

Again, these code is just to demo the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try your suggestion and tell you the out come.

Comment: It works! you are awesome. Though, we need to clear out the socketBuffer after each time drawing image, because the client can click another image and cause crash. Anyway, thanks alot for your help, I can't believe I missed something so basic like size of the pointer at the begining... Good to learn.

Comment: Yeah you are right about the clean up thing. Easy to forget. You are welcome btw :D

Comment: btw, is there any way to avoid looping? since that can hurt performance alot. If client click so fast, the server side might be hang.

Comment: An `int` on Windows/Visual Studio is 4 bytes. It can represent values up to 2^31-1. 64k-1 would be largest representable value for an unsigned 16-bit data type (e.g. `unsigned short`). And a pointer can be 4 **or 8** bytes. Besides all that, your size calculation is wrong. It completely ignores the bits-per-pixel value as well as scanline padding. This solution requires a lot of luck to work.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for comment. Yes I mentioned about int limitation. Pointer size doesn't matter here, just a careless mistake OP made. And about the image size, I used BW (1 bit per pixel) as sample in comment, the colored will be much bigger. But in the program,OP simply uses CBitmap properties to calculate the whole size, that shall be accurate.

Comment: @TrungNguyen Do you have more detail about the hang? Do you mean client side will continue sending data? In that case, the server side made a bit modification. At the read part, make sure it read exact bytes of the package length. I 'll change the code above.

Comment: @EthanF. Your new edition is a bit odd. I tried it and the result is the bitmap displayed UP SIDE DOWN, and then VS throw the Debug Error talking about HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED, and show the problem line is the recv() inside the loop.

Comment: @EthanF. About the first code, this is the debug message talking about "Access violation reading location". And, I figure out that the iLen in the loop, sometime is -1 !! so, I make an `if` wrap outside it to break the loop if the iLen return <0. The picture will not complete at that time, but atleast it doesn't hang the whole dialog. For the send from client side, I find a work around to Sleep(1000) between every click, this will help prevent overflow data from client side, but still not a solution...

Comment: @TrungNguyen Yes you need add some error handling stuff. My code is just showing the idea.  Returning -1 means socket error? Check MSDN for more detail . Sleep is not the good idea. I don't understand even the client keeps sending data it shouldn't cause any crash if  server handles data correctly. Since I don't know the whole code structure I am not able to give more suggestion.

Comment: @TrungNguyen And yes, the second edition code has a bug. Before that readSize is increasing, I forgot to modify the code after I changed it to decreasing . I made the modificiation.

Comment: @EthanF. Thank you for your commentation. So far, your suggestion has anwser my question, and point out my my fault. So I can't ask you to do more. I think I should handle things for myself from now on. Thanks again for your help. Cheer.

Comment: @TrungNguyen You are welcome. And you have right way to go. Your skills will be improved a lot from these debugging thing. Cheers!